# Linker with user32.lib

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to create a windows application but am getting a linker error as follows:

1>test_project.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl run(void)" (?run@@YAHXZ) referenced in function _WinMain@16

I assume this is because user32.lib is not linking correctly, but I have added it to linker->input->additional dependencies and added the directory containing it to library directories. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with user32.lib. Most likely your program contains a forward declaration of function `int run(void);` which you never define yet trying to call from your `WinMain(...)` procedure.